# Pack and unpack complex object architecture with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I've been looking into HTML 5's new local storage and it seems pretty cool so far. I've decided to use JSON to serialize my objects into strings and to parse them back into objects, which all sounds very nice. However, it's easier said than done. I've discovered that you can't just `JSON.stringify()` an object and expect it to pack nicely for you, but I can't figure out what I have to do instead.

That's not all, though: my object contains two arrays, each of which holds another type of object and one of which is multidimensional. Here's what my rather complex and inter-dependent object architecture looks like:

```
function Vector2(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function Bar(ID, position) {
    this.id = id;
    this.position = position;
}

function Goo(state, position) {
    this.on = state;
    this.position = position;
}

function Foo(name, size) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = size;
    this.bars = new Array(width)
    this.goos = new Array(10);

    this.Initialize();
}

Foo.prototype.Initialize() {
    for(var x = 0;x<this.size.x;x++) {
            this.bars[x] = new Array(this.size.y);

        for(var y=0;y<this.size.y;y++) {
            this.bars[x][y] = new Bar(x + y, new Vector2(x, y));
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0;i<this.goos.length;i++) {
        this.goos[i] = new Goo(on, new Vector2(i, i/2 + 1));
    }
}
```

Each of those objects has plenty of additional functions as well, each added using the same prototype method that I used to add the method to Foo. Like I said, complex. My question is, how do I serialize all this? Do I really need to tack on `toJSON()` functions to every object?

Finally, once I've packed all this and saved it to `localstorage`, I know how to retrieve it, but I'm pretty much clueless on how to unpack it with JSON. That's another matter for another time, though, and I suspect it might be a bit easier to figure out on my own once I learn how to pack everything up.

Note: I wouldn't normally such a potentially broad question, but I couldn't really find anything here on SO or with my (admittedly weak) Google-fu that really addresses the issue, and I don't know how to break this question down any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you don't just serialize complex data structures in javascript because the normal serialization doesn't handle multiple difference things all have references to the same object, can't handle circular references, etc...

What I would recommend instead is that you figure out what the real state of your application is.  Not the whole instantiated object structure, but what is the minimum amount of information that is actually needed to reconstruct the state of your data.  Then, once you've figure that out (it should only be data, no actual objects), then you can create functions or methods to get that data from your data structures or create a new data structure from the data.

In looking at your code, the actual state of a `Foo` object is a two dimensional array of `Bar` objects and a one dimensional array of `Goo` objects and a `name` and a `size`.  A `Bar` just has an `x`, `y` and `id`.  A Goo just has a `state` and an `x` and a `y`.  That would be pretty easy state to write a Foo method to generate and a Foo method to accept that state from saved storage.

Comment: So I wouldn't actually serialize the objects, just the stuff I need to reconstruct them? That sounds very promising and, I'll admit, more realistic than just serializing everything... :)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville - yes.  There are languages that let you actually serialize complicated object relationships, but javascript isn't one of those.  Save your data and you can reconstruct the objects from the data.  This also has the advantage that you're just saving the actual data so the save format is not tightly coupled with your implementation scheme.  You can redesign the code and still support the same saved data format.  I would argue that the best data format is 100% independent from your actual implementation so the implementation is free to change.

Comment: That sounds like the right course of action to take. I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, the ride's getting a little bumpy. I can't seem to `stringify` an array of objects. Well, I can, but if I do, I lose all but the first variable on each object in the array. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: It seems to me like you can just call JSON.stringify on the Foo object to create the data.  Then, when you read in that data, you will have to assign each piece of data to a new Foo object.  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4ACcV/) for the stringify example.  FYI, I had to fix a lot of coding errors in the code in your question to get it to run.

Comment: I'm sorry about you having to fix the coding errors, my code was just psuedocode intended to demonstrate the object architecture. Frankly, I'm surprised it even ran at all. :) I'll check out the jsFiddle, thanks. 

EDIT: I see what you mean about stringifying, parsing, then assigning each piece of data to the new Foo object. Thanks a lot for the help, if I could upvote twice, I would. I've learned a lot about how JSON works.

Answer (score 1):

Tacking on toJSON and fromJSON functions is probably the right way to do it. You should only be saving the actual unique data for any given object as JSON, it would not be a good idea to serialize the entire instantiated object for several big reasons, #1 being that it's just unnecessary. Also, think of the case where you add or modify functions for one of your objects in the near future: clients who had stored their own serialized objects, will never get your updates. Simply storing the unique instance data, and having functions to convert that data back to a real object (using your most recent definition) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can pack functions to strings:

```
var a = function() {return "a"};
a.toString()

// And also:

function b() {return "b"};
b.toString();
```

So from there on you could hack the JSON source (by Douglas Crockford) and include support for functions. Or something.

Answer (score -1):

I hope I'm not too late here but I just encountered the same problem.

I wanted to persist a promise object (returned from a JQuery AJAX call) to local storage.

Luckily I stumbled upon a little Javascript library called Stash (http://rezitech.github.io/stash/). It makes both the serialization of complex Javascript objects to Strings and the parsing of a String to a Javascript object possible.

The best thing, you don't have to explicitly perform the serialization/parsing because the data types are automatically recognized and transformed when you want to persist/retrieve an object to/from local storage.

Here is a quick test which yielded a positive result

```
// the api endpoint

var url = "www.api-host.com/api/bla/blub";

// create json call returning promise object

var promise = $.getJSON(url);

// persist promise object in local storage using dash.js

var key = url;

stash.set(key, promise);

// retrieve promise object from local storage

var stashGet = stash.get(key);

// display in console

console.log(stashGet);
```

Regards, Matthias

Comment: This solution doesn't solve his serialization problem.